# how to use pipeline in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipeline

I have a file, I want write a bash shell to do some operations but firstly, I need to sort them and get the top 10 lines of inputfile

my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe= "${1:-/dev/stdin}" > sort -k2    #----line 4
i=0
while [.....]&&[ $i -lt 10 ] do
....
....
i=$((i+1))
done < "$pipe"                      #----line 15
```

The execute command is:

```
cat inputfile | ./e4.sh
```

but I get permission denied:

```
./e4.sh: line 4: /dev/stdin: Permission denied
./e4.sh: line 15: : No such file or directory
```

from my computer I can see the file /dev/stdin

```
root@CP:/dev# ls
block  kmsg  null  pts     shm     stdin   tty   tty1  urandom
fd     lxss  ptmx  random  stderr  stdout  tty0  tty2  zero
```

How to do it correctly.
I mean sort it and get top 10 lines.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Hint '!#` should be `#!` (it's `"pound bang"` NOT `"bang pound"`. There is no `' '` allowed surrounding the assignment operator `'='`. There ARE `' '`s required between `[` and the expression (e.g. `[ expression ]`). After assignment, you reference a variable by preceding its name with `'$'` (e.g. `$i`). The `less than` conditional is `-lt` not `'lt'`. That's all before you get to the problem with redirecting the assignment of `pipe` to `sort`. After [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/), edit your question and the community can help.

Comment: thanks already change

Comment: Which exactly is line 15 where the "No such file or directory" error is reported? We can't tell from you stripped-down lines.

Comment: @StefanHegny I added error line number, so you can find it clearly.

Comment: And what exactly is the intention of line 4? What did you mean to get how into what?

Comment: @Stefan for line 4 I want to get inputfile from default pipeline and sort this by the second column

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a command

```
FOO=BAR BAZ
```

executes the command BAZ in an environment that is augmented by setting the environment variable FOO to the value BAR.

In your case, we have something similar. The command

```
 pipe= "${1-/dev/stdin}" > sort -k2
```

sets the environment variabe named pipe to the empty string, and then invokes the program stored in $1. If $1 is not set, it invokes /dev/stdin. In your case, $1 is not set, so bash tries to execute /dev/stdin, which of course it can't.